# MYSQL - Efficient way of finding if there are any entries in associated table

Tags: mysql

I have a database of orders, the details of which are held in a number of tables; orders, order_items, customers, products, product_items, notes. Each order has one associated entry in the customers and products table, at least one entry in the products_items table. There may or may not be entries for the order with the notes table.

I have the following query to retrieve the order data from which I am creating an array :-

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_items oi  ON oi.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN customer c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN product p ON oi.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_item pi ON pi.product_item_id = oi.product_item_id
```

This works as I need it to, creating a distinct row for each order item. What I am failing to do efficiently is to find out whether an order has any associated notes or not. Using a sub query seems very inefficient (there could be 1000+ orders) and using a JOIN is resulting in order items being duplicated where there is more than one note associated with the order. How can I best find out whether there are any notes?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ..So what do you expect: rows without notes returned or not?

Comment: In only need to know whether notes exist for an order, I don't need to retrieve the actual notes.

Comment: So do you want to get the orders without notes?You cant check if they exists or not without hitting the table

Comment: Yes, I need all the order data, and for each row returned (which will be one per order item) I need to know if that order has any notes associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an outer join on the "notes" table and use the "group_concat" function to avoid duplications.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `notes` is in a different table because it's 1:N and that the id is called note_id.

```
select * from 
(
SELECT distinct(o.order_id) FROM 
orders o, order_items oi, customer c, product p, product_items as pi, notes as n
where o.order_id = oi.order_id
and o.note_id = n.note_id
and o.customer_id = c.customer_id
and p.product_id = oi.product_id
and p.product_id = oi.product_id
) as q,
order  ord
where q.order_id = ord.order_id
```